# Is it safe to make google-service.json (from Firebase) public?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I want to upload my source code of smartphone app to Github, but I am wondering whether I can upload google-service.json, which I got from Firebase UI, together. Does it contain any confidential information? If so, could you teach me a good way to upload the code to Github (assuming the repository is public because I still want to show the code)?

Comment: `google-services.json` does contain some secret stuff. So it's better to not share it.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Actually it does not contain any "secret stuff".  It all gets built into the final app and is easy to reverse engineer. But it's better not to put it in public source control, as it may cause problems for others working on the app using different projects.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out @DougStevenson